# Mi diccionario no funciona en el objeto

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

He puesto 3 diccionarios distinto en el objeto, pero no funciona y no me sale los 3 libros, lo he puesto en el libro1, libro2 y libro 3, del siguiente código de mas abajo. Ya que en el libro dice que debo hacer un código para administrar una biblioteca.

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

class Libro:
  def __init__(self, titulo, autor, editorial, paginas_totales, paginas_leidas):
    self.titulo = titulo
    self.autor = autor
    self.editorial = editorial
    self.paginas_totales = paginas_totales
    self.paginas_leidas = paginas_leidas

  def libro1(self):
    padre_rico_padre_pobre = {"Autor": "Mario Kasnet", "Editorial": "Cabañita", "Paginas Totales": "163"}
    for concepto in padre_rico_padre_pobre:
      print(concepto + ": " + padre_rico_padre_pobre[concepto])

  def libro2(self):
    cien_año_soledad = {"Autor": "Mario Vargas", "Editorial": "Los Laureles", "Paginas Totales": "245"}
    for concepto1 in cien_año_soledad:
      print(concepto1 + ": " + cien_año_soledad[concepto1])

  def libro3(self):
    planta_lima_limon = {"Autor": "Pedro Suarez", "Editorial": "Los Nenes", "Paginas Totales": "133"}
    for concepto2 in planta_lima_limon:
      print(concepto2 + ": " + planta_lima_limon[concepto2])

class Blibioteca(Libro):
  def saludo(self):
    print("Hola")

datos_libro = Biblioteca()

datos_libro.libro1()

datos_libro.libro2()

datos_libro.libro3()

input()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De primeras tu código debe de dar error porque al heredar de la clase padre y ejecutar el inicializador de la clase `Blibioteca` (Que por cierto debería ser `Biblioteca`) no estas pasando ningún parámetro a la clase padre. Esto se soluciona fácilmente, la solución fácil sería pasar los argumentos en la clase `Biblioteca` para que esta la pase a la clase padre. Sin embargo hay una mejor forma de hacerlo y es usando `super`, esto te ayudará en caso tengas hacer herencia múltiple.

De principio experimentando te puedas dar cuenta que haciendo:

```py
class Biblioteca(Libro):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def saludo(self):
        print("Hola")

libro = Biblioteca.libro1()
```

te funcionará, pero no podrás acceder a ningún atributo propio de la clase, por ejemplo `libro.autor` dará error. La solución sería inicializar la clase padre usando `super()` y pasándole los argumentos necesarios.

```py
class Biblioteca(Libro):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("Algun_titulo", "Algun_autor", "Alguna_editorial", "num_paginas", "pag_leidas")
    def saludo(self):
        print("Hola")

libro = Biblioteca()
libro.libro1()
print(libro.autor)
```

Con esto todo ya estaría correcto. Si quieres evitarte pasar los argumentos a la clase padre entonces debes ponerle un valor por defecto, por ejemplo `""` (vacío) o `None`.

```py
class Libro:
  def __init__(self, titulo=None, autor=None, editorial=None, paginas_totales=None, paginas_leidas=None):
  # resto del código
```

Incluso puedes mejorar esto aún más, puedes utilizar `kwargs` en la clase hija para evitar pasar cada argumento y en su lugar pasar un diccionario de argumentos.

Con la modificación anterior podríamos sumarle esto:

```py
class Biblioteca(Libro):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def saludo(self):
        print("Hola")

argumentos = {
    "titulo":"Algun_titulo", 
    "autor": "Algun_autor", 
    "editorial": "Alguna_editorial", 
    "paginas_totales": "num_paginas", 
    "paginas_leidas": "pag_leidas"
}
libro = Biblioteca(**argumentos)
libro.libro1()
print(libro.autor)
```

Incluso puedes omitir argumentos ya que en la clase padre ya tienen un valor por defecto. Si tienes alguna duda puedes decírmela en los comentarios :D.

Comment: pero en el libro decía que cuando una class hereda, lo hereda todo sus métodos y argumentos del otro class.

Comment: Sí, efectivamente se hereda, pero debes de inicializar la clase padre

Comment: sabes si un método de una class se puede imprimir con una condición de if ==

Comment: No he entendido tu pregunta, podrías ser más claro? O si consideras que es muy extenso puedes formular una nueva pregunta

Comment: Ósea quiero que al poner if self.titulo == "Padre rico y padre pobre":, me salga todo el diccionario del libro1 y al if self.titulo == "Cien años de solead":, me salga todo el diccionario del libro2.

Comment: si se puede, pero creo que debes de especificar más y dar un mayor ejmplo. Te recomiendo formular otra pregunta

Comment: ya lo estoy desarrollando, me salió pero no es como quiero :C

Answer (score 0):

Faltan los parámetros posicionales del constructor Biblioteca()

```
datos_libro = Biblioteca("", "", "", "", "")
```

La solución de Christian también es válida:

```
class Biblioteca(Libro):
  def __init__(self):
    super()
  def saludo(self):
    print("Hola")
```

Comment: Pero esta heredando los metodos de Libro, con Biblioteca(Libro):

Comment: Tienes razón. El problema es que no le estás pasando los parámetros necesarios al constructor `Biblioteca()`. Edité la respuesta con el nuevo constructor.

Comment: Solución usa `super()` para inicializar la clase Padre

Comment: He tenido que darte un voto negativo por la muy mala solución que has brindado, no es nada pythonico

Comment: @Christian entendible. No soy un experto en Python

Comment: Al cambiar el datos_libro = Libro(), me funciono, pero al intentar ponerle el libro1, libro2 y libro3 debajo de clase biblioteca ya no funciona, hasta cambie el datos_libro = biblioteca()

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta con tu nuevo código?